# How can I combine multiple functions with ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets

I've the below formula using `ImportRange` and `Query` along with `Join` and `Split` working correctly:

```
=join(" / ", QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Google-Sheet-ID","RawData!A:AC"),"select Col25 where Col1 = " & JOIN(" OR Col1 = ", split(V2:V,"+")), 0))
```

Also, I've the below `ArrayFormula` with `Split` function working smoothly:

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(V2:V)=0,,split(V2:V,"+")))
```

But When I tried combining them together using the below formula:

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(V2:V)=0,,join(" / ", QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Google-Sheet-ID","RawData!A:AC"),"select Col25 where Col1 = " & JOIN(" OR Col1 = ", split(V2:V,"+")), 0))))
```

It failed, and gave me the below error:

> Error
>   Function SPLIT parameter 1 value should be non-empty.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ySTdv-vS4nBYi6Y9X3bWb4aurIvjX1lbdUSmXJrQoHw/edit?usp=sharing) is my sheet for your testing.

**UPDATE**

I changed it to:

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(C2:C)=0,,JOIN(" OR Col1 = ", ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(C2:C)=0,,split(C2:C,"+"))))))
```

So my full formula is:

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(
if(
   len(C2:C)=0,,
join(" / ", 
QUERY(
     IMPORTRANGE("14iNSavtvjRU0XipPWIMKyHNwXTA85P_CafFTsIPHI6c","RawData!A:AC"),"select Col25 where Col1 = " & 
        ARRAYFORMULA(
           if(len(C2:C)=0,,
              JOIN(" OR Col1 = ", 
                  ARRAYFORMULA(
                     if(
                         len(C2:C)=0,,split(C2:C,"+")
                      )
                  )
               )
            )
        ),

    0
))))
```

And now getting the error:

> Error
>   JOIN range must be a single row or a single column.

Comment: Share a sample, please

Comment: @contributorpw https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ySTdv-vS4nBYi6Y9X3bWb4aurIvjX1lbdUSmXJrQoHw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the overall Goal?  Can you explain in words, the goal of the query?  That is something like "Show me all of the ETA column from this Imported sheet where [ list of conditons]"

Comment: @MattKing you almost hit it, Goal: 'Show me all of the ETA column from this Imported sheet where shipment ID is in the given list'

Comment: @HasanAYousef ok, i can do that, but is the 'list' in both column A and B? You have those labeled as 'Item' and 'Size'. Also there are only 2 shipments in the sample, so it will be a little hard to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing this with Apps Script? You can get the values from the Sheet2, Shipment Ids, and the Ids from MK.Testing and compare them. If they coincide, the you copy the ETA into the Column C of MK. Testing:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet2 = sprsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var mkTesting = sprsheet.getSheetByName("MK.Testing");

  var shipmentId = sheet2.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var idList = mkTesting.getRange("A2:A").getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < shipmentId.length; i++){

    for (var j = 0; j < idList.length; j++){

      if (idList[j][0] == ""){break;} //Stops if there is an empty cell in Mk.Testing's column A

      if (idList[j][0] === shipmentId[i][0]){

        var eta = sheet2.getRange("E"+(i+2)).getValue();

        mkTesting.getRange("C"+(j+2)).setValue(eta);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

**References:**

- [SpreadsheetApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this formula on the tab called MK.Testing will pull the info you're hoping for.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("14iNSavtvjRU0XipPWIMKyHNwXTA85P_CafFTsIPHI6c","RawData!A:AC"),"select Col25 where Col1="&TEXTJOIN(" or Col1=",TRUE,A2:A))
```

I think you might have been overcomplicating things?  This formula just forms a text string out of the shipment IDs to use in a query.  one thing that may be tripping you up is that query() is very particular about the *type* of data in a column.  Your shipment IDs can be numbers, or they can be number letter combos, but not both.  That is, if you have some shipment IDs that contain letters and others that don't, it will be more difficult to get a query that works. (though not impossible).  For the sake of helping you though, it's important that your sample IDs reflect the real ones in this way as accurately as possible.

Comment: My concern is I want to use Array formula to get it executed along the full column, this is why it got complicated with me

Comment: Ah. Well I can do that too, did you want to have a list of shipments in a single cell then? Maybe comma separated?